# How to define a template specific type that can be inherited?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

My question might not be as clear as I would like.
Let me explain.
I have an abstract mother class M, and a lot of child class C1,C2,...Cn.
In each child, I have to define template types like this:

```
class Child1 : public Mother
{
    public:
    typedef AnotherTemplateClass<Child1,int>         Type1_C1;
    typedef AnotherTemplateClass<Child1,bool>        Type2_C1;
    typedef AnotherTemplateClass<Child1,unsigned>    Type3_C1;
    void DoSomething(Type1_C1 a, Type2_C1 b, Type3_C1);
};
```

I would like to define something like:

```
class Mother
{    
    public:
    typedef AnotherTemplateClass<this,int>          Type1_M;
    typedef AnotherTemplateClass<this,bool>         Type2_M;
    typedef AnotherTemplateClass<this,unsigned>     Type3_M;
};
```

and with Child1 using this type

```
class Child1 : public Mother
{
    void DoSomething(Type1_M a, Type2_M b, Type3_M c);
};
```

I know that is not possible to do that

`error: invalid use of ‘this’ at top level`

but is there any syntax that could answer this problem?

is that even possible?

Comment: What is `Callback`? Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: callback is just a template class. I changed its name for you not to misunderstand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRTP might help:

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
class ChildCrtp : public Mother
{
    public:
    typedef AnotherTemplateClass<Derived,int>         Type1_C1;
    typedef AnotherTemplateClass<Derived,bool>        Type2_C1;
    typedef AnotherTemplateClass<Derived,unsigned>    Type3_C1;

    Possibly:
    //void DoSomething(Type1_C1 a, Type2_C1 b, Type3_C1);
};
```

and then

```cpp
class Child1 : public ChildCrtp<Child1>
{
public:
    void DoSomething(Type1_C1 a, Type2_C1 b, Type3_C1);
};
```

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: I kept `Mother` inheritance in CRTP.

Comment: oh sorry overlooked that. Its such a common misunderstanding that I panicked without reading carefully